# how do I record output from a Roland voice transformer (midi or 1/4" output) on a Zoom recorder (XLR input)?

Tags: midi, xlr, voice-manipulation

I record instructional videos for work and fun.

The audio is captured via a Rode NTG2 mic into a Zoom H4n record. Phantom power is provided to the mic by the recorder.

I'd like to manipulate my voice with a Roland voice transformer (VT-3 or VT-4). This device has XLR (w/ phantom power) input - perfect. The output options are 1/4" jacks or midi. My Zoom recorded is expecting XLR input.

How can I take the midi or output from the 1/4" jacks and capture it in my Zoom recorder? Perhaps I have completely the wrong idea about what it means to add voice effects to a video. Is this purely a post-production step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure you can get a cable and/or adapters to interface these devices...the H4n XLR inputs are "combo jacks" that also accept balanced or unbalanced 1/4" plugs. (maybe you didn't know this?)

However, MIDI is a no-go for this, as it is purely data communication for device control. (eg; to connect a keyboard controller to a sound module or sequencer)

Comment: Thanks @Tyler. That's excellent. I never inspected the input ports on the H4n closely. I thought they were just plain XLR.